# How to interpret Fourier-Stieltjes transform on $\mathbb T$ (one dimesional torus)?

Tags: measure-theory, fourier-analysis, representation-theory, harmonic-analysis, banach-algebras

Let $\mu$ be a regular Borel measure on $\mathbb Z$ and we put, 
$$\|\mu\|:= |\mu| (\mathbb Z)= \text {total variation of} \ \mu . $$
and define

$$M(\mathbb Z):= \{\mu: P(\mathbb Z)\to \mathbb C : \mu \ \text{is regular and } \ \|\mu\|< \infty \}$$
If $\mu \in M(\mathbb Z)$, the function $\hat{\mu}$ defined on $\mathbb T$ by
$$\hat{\mu}(e^{i\theta})= \int_{\mathbb Z} e^{-in \theta} d\mu(n); (e^{i\theta} \in \mathbb T)$$
is called the [Fourier-Stieltjes transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_algebra) of $\mu$ and we define

$$B(\mathbb T) := \{f:\mathbb T \to \mathbb C : \exists \ \mu \in M(\mathbb Z) \  \text {such that} \ f(y) = \hat{\mu}(y)  \}.$$

**My naive Questions are**: 
**(1)** What are members of $M(\mathbb Z)$  and the what are its corresponding members in $B(\mathbb T)$ ?

**My attempt**: 
Example: Fix $n_{0}\in \mathbb Z$ and consider  [Dirac measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_measure) $\delta_{n_{0}}: P(\mathbb Z) \to  \{0,1 \}$ then $\delta_{n_{0}}\in M(\mathbb Z)$; now let us try to compute corresponding member of $B(\mathbb T)$; namely, $\hat{\delta_{n_{0}}}(e^{i\theta})= \int_{\mathbb Z} e^{-in\theta} d\delta_{n_{0}}(n)$; 
but, now I don't know how to interpret this last integral ? (I want to see few more specific examples of different types)

**(2)** How to prove, $B(\mathbb T)= A(\mathbb T):= \{f:\mathbb T \to \mathbb C : \exists \ g\in \ell^{1}(\mathbb Z) \ \text {such that} \  f(e^{i\theta})= \hat{g}(e^{i\theta})\} $

**My attempt**:

Let $f\in A(\mathbb T)$. Then there is  a $g\in \ell^{1}(\mathbb Z)$ such that $\hat{g}(e^{i\theta})=f(e^{i\theta})$, that is, $\sum_{n\in \mathbb Z} g(n)e^{-in\theta} = f(e^{i\theta})$. I must show, $f\in B(\mathbb T)$, that is to find $\mu \in M(\mathbb Z)$ such that $f(e^{i\theta})=\hat{\mu} (e^{i \theta})= \int_{\mathbb Z} e^{-in\theta} d\mu (n);$ the hypothesis suggests me that, I should take, $\mu:P(\mathbb Z)\to \mathbb C$, in terms of $g$, but I don’t know precisly how to take $\mu$;

On the other hand, let $f\in B(\mathbb T)$. Then there exists $\mu \in M(\mathbb Z)$ such that $\hat{\mu}(e^{i\theta})= f(e^{i\theta})$.  I must show, $f\in A(\mathbb T)$, that is, to find $g\in \ell^{1}(\mathbb Z)$ such that, $\hat{g}(e^{i\theta})= f(e^{i\theta})$; so the hypothesis suggests that, take a $g$ such that, $\hat{g}(e^{i\theta})= \hat{\mu}(e^{i\theta})$; by some thing like uniqueness theorem, $\mu = g$ (I am not sure here, this is bit vague!) and my confusion is  here $\mu$ is a set function define on $P(\mathbb Z) $ while $g$ is function define on $\mathbb Z$ ?

---

**Definitions**: Let $\mathbb Z$ be a topological space with the discrete topology and take $B=P(\mathbb Z)$= the power set of $\mathbb Z$, as the  Borel sets on $\mathbb Z$ and a measure on $\mathbb Z$ is a set function $\mu$, defined for all Borel sets of $\mathbb Z$, which is countably additive and for which the $\mu (E)$ is finite if the closure of $E$ is compact. For each measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb Z$ there is  associated set function $|\mu|$, the total variation of $\mu$ is defined by , $|\mu|(E)= \sup \sum |\mu(E_{i})|$, the supremum being taken over all finite collections of pairwise disjoints Borel sets $E_{i}$ whose union is $E$. We note that $|\mu|$ is also a measure on $\mathbb Z$. If $|\mu|(E)=\sup |\mu|(K)= \inf |\mu|(v)$ for every Borel set $E$,  where $K$ ranges over all compact subset of $E$ and $V$ ranges over all open supersets of $E$, then $\mu$ is called a ***regular***.

Comment: Regularity is kind of an overkill since you have a discrete space, no? If you look at probability measures on $\mathbb{Z}$, which span your $M(\mathbb{Z})$, then their image under the Fourier-transform would be the positive-definite functions on the compact group $\mathbb{T}$. This is Gelfand-Bochner theorem. (The special case where you switch the roles of the integers and the circle in your question is actually kinda pretty and leads directly to spectral analysis of covariance-stationary discrete time stochastic processes.)